# android ListView footer update

Tags: android, listview, footer

i have a shopping cart done with ListView and i am showing totals on the ListView  footer.
i have added the footer view to the listView using,

GetShoppingCartItems - gets current items in the shopping cart

fillBasketSummary create the footer

DoRemoveCartItem - remove item from the cart

```
private Handler handler = new Handler() 
    { 

       public void handleMessage(Message msg) 
       { 

               fillBasketSummary() ;
               dialog.dismiss() ; 


       }
    } ;


 private void GetShoppingCartItems()
    {
        try {
            WsFpUser wsfp = myapp.getWsFP_User() ;
            products = wsfp.GetBasketOrderItems(loggedInUser.ID);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

        handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
    }



private void fillBasketSummary()
    {
        try {

             LayoutInflater inflater =  this.getLayoutInflater();
             View footerView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.basket_footer, null);

             ListView lst = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.basket_listItems);

             lst.addFooterView(footerView);


            if (adapter != null)
            {
                adapter.products.clear() ;
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() ;
            }

            if (products != null)
            {
                lstProducts = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.basket_listItems);
                adapter = new ProductsAdapter(getApplicationContext(), products);
                lstProducts.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
            else
            {
                // show message "cart empty"

            }

             float subTotal = 0.0f ;

             DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");


            TextView txtSubTotal = (TextView) footerView.findViewById(R.id.basket_txtSubTotal);         

            if (products != null)
            {
                 for (int i =0; i< products.size() ; i ++)
                 {
                        float price = Float.parseFloat(product.itemPrice) ;
                        float discount = Float.parseFloat(product.itemDiscount) ;
                        int quantity = Integer.parseInt(product.quantity); 
                        subTotal = subTotal + (price - discount) * quantity ;

                 }

                txtSubTotal.setText("£ " + df.format(subTotal));

            }


        } catch (Exception e) 
        {
            Log.e("err",e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    }


public void DoRemoveCartItem(final int itemIndex)
   {



        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", 
                "Loading. Please wait...", true);

        Thread t = new Thread(  new Runnable()  {
             public void run() 
             {
                 boolean bRemove = false;
                 WsFpUser wsfpUser = myapp.getWsFP_User() ;
                 CardItem cardItem = products.get(itemIndex);

                 try 
                 {
                     bRemove = wsfpUser.RemoveOrderItem(cardItem.orderID);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                 if (bRemove) 
                 {
                     GetShoppingCartItems();
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     // error
                 }

             }

        }) ;
        t.start() ;



   }
```

To remove items I call DoRemoveCartItem() then calls "GetShoppingCartItems()" to get the current item list  then it rebuild the list

Every time user remove item from the list i recalculate the totals and do the above process to add footer again.

The problem is the footer values does not get updated when items are removed from the list.

what did i do wrong?

Comment: Where is it actually that you're updating your footer?

Comment: My guess is that you aren't updating the footer view when the list view is updated.

Comment: when item is removed from the cart. i call web service to get current data for the ListView. After data received I reload the listview 

modified the code to show what was done ...

Comment: previously i had the adding the footer part after the " if (adapter != null)" section

then the footer does not get displayed, is there a sequence to adding footer?

Comment: I thinking posting snippets makes it hard for us to find the problem. How do we know subTotal is changing? Where is that updated? Can you post *more* code that is relevant? Method calls, value updates, loops, etc..? Are all of these snippets you posted in the same method? Or different ones?

Comment: i have updated the code section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems the order you add the footer has some effect how it get created. I did the following to get it working

```
ListView lst = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.basket_listItems);



             if (lst.getFooterViewsCount() > 0)
             {
                 lst.removeFooterView(footerView);
             }


             LayoutInflater inflater =  this.getLayoutInflater();
             footerView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.basket_footer, null);
             lst.addFooterView(footerView);

             this.onContentChanged();

            if (adapter != null)
            {
                ...
```

**this.onContentChanged();** is the critical line.

it seems to create the ListView again. I am not sure this is the correct way to do it but it worked for me.